# passing an array of hash to server with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, hash

i have an array like this

```
places = new Array();
places.push({name: "ci", loc: "bo"})
places.push({name: "ae", loc: "ea"})

if i try to send this data to server with this:
jQuery.ajax({type: "POST", url: "import", 
              data: { "places[]": places, kind: "pub" }, 

            });
```

doesn't work. 
i receive an array of javascript objects

how can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the array to a JSON string:

```
jQuery.ajax({type: "POST", 
             url: "import", 
             data: {places: JSON.stringify(places), kind: "pub" }
            });
```

and on the server side, decode the string. If you use PHP, it would be [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$places = json_decode($_POST['places'], true);
```